# how to overwrite Magento_CatalogSearch etc/search_request.xml file?

Tags: magento2, catalogsearch, php-7

As i want to add custom limit for my catalog page, so I need to add size in search_request.xml file. but as it in vendor folder, need to overerite it.

any help will be appreciated.
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple for overwrite and follow below instruction.

Go to your custom theme and create directory as per below.

```
/var/www/html/magento243/app/design/frontend/<vendorname>/<customthemename>/Magento_CatalogSearch/etc/
```

Copy this `search_request.xml` file from vendor and paste in custom theme directory.

That it!!

Comment: I have check but it's not working

we need to create custom extension and add in sequence for Magento_CatalogSearch

Answer (score 0):

You can't change the core file directly. so you need to override the file in your module.